# Call stored procedures in GUI through controller?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

Im using linq-to-sql in C# and have created a stored procedure in sql-server called "ShowMember". I have connected this procedure in C# through linq-to-sql.

When I directly connect my stored procedure to my GUI it works:

```
    Database_NightClubDataContext dal = new Database_NightClubDataContext();
    private void btnAddMember_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ShowNewMember = dal.ShowMember();
        dataGridViewMember.DataSource = ShowNewMember;
    }
```

But I don't want to connect the database directly in the GUI, i want to do it through my controller class. I tried creating a method in the controller and calling on it in the GUI, but it doesn't work. How should the method be written in the controller?

I tried this for example, but obviously it didn't work..

```
namespace Nightclub
{
    class Controller
    {
      Database_NightClubDataContext dal = new Database_NightClubDataContext();
      public Member ShowNewMember()
      {
        var ShowM = dal.ShowMember();
        return ShowM;
      }             
    }
}
```

Comment: **How** doesn't it work?

Comment: This controller class, is it an MVC controller?

Comment: Yes it's an MVC controller!

Comment: I tried this for example, but obviously it didn't work..                                       namespace Nightclub
{
    class Controller
    {
      Database_NightClubDataContext dal = new Database_NightClubDataContext();
      public Member ShowNewMember()
    {
        var ShowM = dal.ShowMember();
        return ShowM;
    }             
    }
    }

Comment: if i where you I'll upgrade to EF6 
see this link http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20First%20Insert%2fUpdate%2fDelete%20Stored%20Procedure%20Mapping

Comment: MVC controller?? You're clearly writing Windows Forms (not ASP.Net MVC). Nevertheless, also in WinForms it's a good idea to use controllers of some kind. Controllers should pass data to a view (a Form) and respond to commands from the view. But your code is too sketchy to expand on.